# Will the content I create on Confluence in my personal space be deleted when I leave an organization?

Tags: jira, confluence

https://confluence.atlassian.com/ offers user an option to create a personal space where we can maintain all the documents and information related to work.

I am concerned, if content of my personal space be deleted after I leave the organization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Content created by any user is not deleted automatically in any
>   case

We can refer to following confluence documentation, which specifies three actions for users leaving organization, [disable/unsync/delete], in all the cases the content is maintained.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/delete-or-disable-users-138318.html

Personal spaces are not deleted
When you delete a user, their personal space is not automatically deleted, as it may contain content owned by your organization

Answer (score 0):

The user full name as mentioned in the references may be changed to his user name, if confluence is not able to get it for any reason. Nevertheless the content is left untouched.